# Check that a string is a valid JavaScript identifier name using Python 3

Tags: javascript, string, python-3.x, lexer

If I understand the two specs correctly, JavaScript and Python 3 use the exact same rules for variable names, except that JavaScript also allows dollar characters in its names.

Python 3 provides an `isidentifier` string method that returns `True` if the string is a valid Python 3 identifier, and `False` otherwise. That method knows which unicode characters can be used in a name, but obviously doesn't allow dollar characters.

The following expression is simplistic:

```
string.replace("$", "").isidentifier()
```

It incorrectly evaluates to `False` on a name that:

- only contains dollar characters (`$` or `$$$` for example)
- only has dollar characters prior to a digit (`$123` or `$$0foo` )

What's the most idiomatic way to check a string is a valid JavaScript identifier name in Python 3?

Comment: Why not replace with a valid python character e.g. `.replace('$', '_')`, your examples would all evaluate to `True`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. You should make that an answer. Thanks.

Comment: The rules for ECMAScript identifiers are here: [*EMCA-262 §11.6*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-IdentifierStart).